# How do you organize your template structure in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I will be building a CMS for my final Web Development course project, and i've been challenged by my teacher creating it in an MVC system, and for now, I'll be using CodeIgniter.

Therefore, I would like to know how do you organize your file / folder structure.

I will be using a simple templating system:
- For now I have a templates.php config file that is being autoloaded and says the name of the selected template, and the absolute path to it.
- The templates folder is inside the views folder (is this the most correct way to do this?)
- Right now I am having some problem to access .css files through the files in the view, and, from what I've read people usually put all that files outside the application folder.

How do you normally do it? And, as seeing what I am building, what advices can you give me?
Shouldn't views contain all the stuff from templates? (including CSS inside the folder of templates)

Thanks.

*(i'm using the Code Ignitor 2.1.0)*

EDIT:

Right now, after structured all the files and folders, I am in a dilemma. I have added the following in constants.php

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
$config['selected_template'] = 'oceania';
$config['template_abs_path'] = 'assets/templates/'.$config['selected_template'];

define('IMAGES_PATH', $config['template_abs_path'].'/img/' );
define('CSS_PATH', $config['template_abs_path'].'/css/' );
define('SCRIPTS_PATH', $config['template_abs_path'].'/js/' );
```

(if I didn't define the selected_template and template_abs_path I could play with them in the constants)

And i'm including them in the HTML like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=CSS_PATH;?>style.css" />
```

But now, I was trying to get a title stored in config too, but I can't do it, because I need all this variables to be in the other templates.php file that I had created previously, otherwise it will not recognize my variables. (I have templates autoloading)

templates.php

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['title'] = 'Title of the website';
$config['selected_template'] = 'oceania';
$config['template_abs_path'] = 'templates/'.$config['selected_template'];
```

header.php

```
<div id="logo">
<h1><a href="#"><?=$this->config->item('title');?></a></h1>
</div>
```

Therefore, do I need to have both config to have it working on my website? It really doesn't make much sense for me...

Comment: All public files (images, js scripts, css files etc) should be under document root. All other files should never be under document root (except for the bootstrap file).

Comment: But if I have a templating system, should I repeat the folders templates/name_of_the_template in the root and in the views folder? Because I can have different files...

Comment: I usually keep my views simple, just plain old PHP files and layouts etc.  There is no reason to mix up your Assets with your views, CSS/images/JS can be placed in its own folders.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A good file/folder structure would be the below:

```
website_folder/
–––– application/
–––––––– config/
–––––––––––– autoload.php
–––––––––––– config.php
–––––––––––– ...
–––––––– controllers/
–––––––––––– examples.php
–––––––––––– index.html
–––––––––––– welcome.php
–––––––– ...
–––––––– views/
––––––––---- templates/
––––––––-------- backend.php
––––––––-------- frontend.php
–––––––––––– ....
–––––––––––– example.php
–––––––––––– index.html
–––––––––––– welcome_message.php    
–––– assets/
–––––––– css/
–––––––– js/
–––––––– images/
–––––––– templates/
––––––––---- frontend/
––––––––-------- css/
––––––––-------- js/
––––––––-------- images/
––––––––---- backend/   
––––––––-------- css/
––––––––-------- js/
––––––––-------- images/
–––––––– uploads/
–––––––– index.html
–––– system/
–––– user_guide/
–––– index.php
–––– license.txt
```

This is just a suggestion. So you will have your template views at views/templates and your css/js files at assets/templates/

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will be using this in my future templates project. I think it is really what I needed. :)

Answer (score 2):

I am totally agreed with web-johnny file folder structure but in my opinion he missed one thing define all your assets path in ./application/config/constants.php file e.g.

```
define('IMAGES_PATH', your_absolute_path_of_images_folder);
define('CSS_PATH', your_absolute_path_of_css_folder);
define('SCRIPTS_PATH', your_absolute_path_of_scripts_folder);
```

and so on... use these constants throughout the application so in this way if you ever need to change your file folder structure you just need to change the values of these constants.

Comment: I've used your suggestion, but right now, I have another problem. Could you take a look at the main post please?

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Modular Extensions [HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home), it's really useful when your project starts to grow. Modular Extensions - HMVC makes the CodeIgniter PHP framework modular. Modules are groups of independent components (typically, controller, model and view) arranged in one application sub-directory that can be dropped into other CodeIgniter applications.

Comment: That sounds a very cool addon anw, but right now I will stick with the better file and folder structure. :) Thanks!