# Stylesheet not getting attached in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am new to CI and I tried to use the normal HMTL file as template. So I made a folder in 'application/views' named 'education'. I made a header.php, navigation.php, content.php and footer.php file. In the controller I wrote

```
class Education extends CI_Controller {
 function index() {
   $this->load->view('education/header');
   $this->load->view('education/navigation');
   $this->load->view('education/content');
   $this->load->view('education/footer');
 }
}
```

Then I accessed the link like "http://localhost:8080/mvc/index.php/education/"

But the stylesheet is not getting attached, which is in the same folder as the files. I also tried changing the href of the stylesheet link to "echo base_url();application/views/education/style.css". But it din't work either.

Any help

thanks

Comment: In which view you are loading your css?

Comment: In the header file it was included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't keep style sheets/js files/images in your application folder.. Keep them outside the application folder in some folder like "static" and access them using `base_url()`

A good file/folder structure would be the below:

```
website_folder/
–––– application/
–––––––– config/
–––––––––––– autoload.php
–––––––––––– config.php
–––––––––––– ...
–––––––– controllers/
–––––––––––– examples.php
–––––––––––– index.html
–––––––––––– welcome.php
–––––––– ...
–––––––– views/
––––––––---- templates/
––––––––-------- backend.php
––––––––-------- frontend.php
–––––––––––– ....
–––––––––––– example.php
–––––––––––– index.html
–––––––––––– welcome_message.php    
–––– assets/
–––––––– css/
–––––––– js/
–––––––– images/
–––––––– templates/
––––––––---- frontend/
––––––––-------- css/
––––––––-------- js/
––––––––-------- images/
––––––––---- backend/   
––––––––-------- css/
––––––––-------- js/
––––––––-------- images/
–––––––– uploads/
–––––––– index.html
–––– system/
–––– user_guide/
–––– index.php
–––– license.txt
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458484/how-do-you-organize-your-structure-in-codeigniter) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656894/how-can-i-display-images-with-the-codeigniter-php-framework)..

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Another thing, I have called images from stylesheet which is not displayed. any idea?

Comment: @Roger images from stylesheets? I didn't get you.. Please explain a bit more

Comment: I got that. I was telling about like my stylesheet has some thing like
    background-image:url('images/bg.jpg');
so how to edit that?

Comment: @Roger That should work fine.. assuming your images are not in the application folder..

Comment: It Worked. but as I kept the css file and Images folder in a same folder thats why I was getting confused. My mistake ;)

Answer (score 0):

File: (your_site)/application/views/education/header.php

```
....
<LINK href="/static/some.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
....
```

File (your_site)/static/some.css

```
....
 some styles
....
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Another thing, I have called images from stylesheet which is not displayed. any idea?

Comment: place your image as <your site>/static/images/image.jpg; use background-image:url('/static/images/image.jpg') in css;

Comment: http://www.rxs-enterprises.org/fp/articles/9988/10/37/40/Relative_and_Absolute_Addressing.aspx

Comment: I tried to modify the style-sheet values but it didn't work for me. I made a folder named 'education' in the same folder where 'application','system','user_guide' folders are placed. Then in the Education folder I placed the CSS file and Images folder. But its not working. The CSS file is getting attached but the image files that are being called from the CSS file is not getting the path.

Comment: I changed that . But its not getting the files

Comment: need more information (folders/files structure, code of html header and css).

Comment: I noticed one thing. I used Firebug to check the url. The url of the files are coming like " background-image: url("/education/image/header.jpg");".
But if I change that to " background-image: url("http://localhost:8080/mvc/education/image/header.jpg");", then the images are coming.

What am I missing here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21861/discussion-between-roger-and-thehorse)